# What is a stoquastic Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, computational-physics, quantum-computer, lattice-model

Recently, I've often read about the term 'stoquastic Hamiltonian'. But I couldn't find a precise definition anywhere. I found that the Ising-Hamiltonian is a stoquastic Hamiltonian, but that does not help a lot...

Can anyone give a precise definition?

Edit: Here's a paper where such a 'stoquastic Hamiltonian' is mentioned.
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0606140

Comment: Probably useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317711/25301

Comment: Also, it looks like Bravyi mentions the answer to your question on page 2 of the PDF in the arXiv link; can you explain what is lacking in the definition given there?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The paper says "[...]all oﬀ-diagonal matrix elements are real and non-positive." Is that really all?

Comment: Do you mean Stochastic?

Comment: @alfC I thought so too, but the linked paper does actually say "stoquastic." (It also gives a definition in the very first sentence of the abstract, so it's hard to see the need for this question.)

Comment: This has got to be my least favorite physics coinage of all time!

Comment: @knzhou You can always use "sign-problem free" instead.

Answer (score 6):

Hamiltonians where all the off-diagonal elements in the standard basis are real and non-positive are called "stoquastic."